# GitHub Issues: Closed date is before created date!!! Wha..?

Tags: git, github, github-issues

E.g.:

- comments/actions [start 35 mins before](https://github.com/Jackett/Jackett/issues/10042) issue was opened
- comments/actions [start 24 mins before](https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/5677) issue was opened
- comments/actions [start ~1.5mths before](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22240) issue was opened

..clearly we can see threads are  created **after** being closed as completed.

Is this possible in some scenarios? If not, what kind of error can cause this?

Comment: Loooks like some of the following comments also have a older date than the opening post. Looks like a bug that somehow updated timestamps of opening posts.

Comment: The comments are older than the actual post, so I initially thought it was due to editing the original post, but edits still show the original timestamp and with the edit history(if anyone else is wondering the same). I'm not sure but can daylight saving time has a role in this?

Comment: This is real mystery for me. I'll watch for updates on this one. For the first 2 linked, I though it would be something related to synchronisation and where users are located somehow. For Spring Boot, not sure how is it possible. I thought going through milestones, maybe they added in some completed milestone so that's why it's closed before it's opened.